# Proof verification of convergence of a real sequence. (basics)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $(a_n)$ be a real sequence of (strictly) positive numbers converging to zero as $n\to\infty$. Assume that for $c\in(0,1)$,
$$a_n^2\geq \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^c}, \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.\quad (A1)$$
Prove that,  as $n\to\infty$,

1. $\frac{\ln n}{na_n^2}\to 0$;
2. $\frac{\ln n}{na_n}\to 0$;
3. $\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^ca_n}\leq 1$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

**My proof**

The symbol "$\implies$" means "imply", while "$\to$" means "tends to, as $n\to\infty$".

(1) From (A1), since $(\ln n)^3\geq \ln n$ and $c\in (0,1)$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{a^2_nn}{\ln n}\geq n^{1-c}\to\infty \implies \frac{\ln n}{a_n^2n}\to0.
\end{equation}

(2)For all $n$ large enough so that $a_n\leq 1$, we have $a_n\geq a_n^2$. Then, using (1),
\begin{equation}
\frac{\ln n}{a_nn}\leq \frac{\ln n}{a_n^2n}, \forall n:a_n\leq 1\overset{(1)}{\implies}\frac{\ln n}{a_nn}\to 0.
\end{equation}

(3)The observation in (2) that $a_n\geq a_n^2$ for $n$ large together with  (A1) immediately imply the result.

**Are all arguments clean and clear?**

Comment: Looks correct to me except 1) it should also be mentioned that $n\gt 1$, 2) First you mentioned $n$ large enough but then inequality just after that is valid for all $n$ and $a_n\ge 1$?I suppose that’s a typo there.

Comment: For brevity's sake I wrote "$\forall n: a_n\geq 1$" meaning  "for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\geq 1$" .

Comment: Then it is not correct. Please note that: if $a_n\ge 1$ then you can’t say that $a_n\ge a_n ^2$. Since $a_n\to 0$ there exists $N$ such that $n\ge N \implies a_n\lt 1$ that is for all $n\ge N$, we have $\frac{\ln n}{a_n n}\lt \frac{\ln n}{a_n^2 n}$ (because $a_n \lt 1$ for all $n\ge N$) etc.

Comment: @Koro You are right. I didn't notice the inequality was reversed. I thought you didn't understand the notation. Thanks